# connection issues when MLFLow is hosted on remote server

Tags: python, redhat, mlflow, mlops

I have hosted mlflow server on redhat server (http://) with mlflow_trk.service file which contains this:

```
[Unit]
Description=MLflow tracking server
After=network.target 

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c PATH=/venv/bin/:$PATH exec mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://<username>:<password>@<DB_host>:<DB_Port>/mlflow -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I then set the tracking uri to "http://<ip_of_server>/mlflow_trk" and then I run the code I get these errors:

- mlflow. exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name failed with error code 403 != 200.
- urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx', port=xxx): Max retries exceeded with url: /mlflow-tracking/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name?experiment_name=xxx (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable')))

Can u please help me achieve this connection.

Tried adding nginx but it does not seem to be working.